# Page refresh issue(404) on server - Angular

Tags: angular, .htaccess, server, build

I build an Angular project. It's working fine on my local machine but on the server, whenever I refresh my page on some deep routes, it gives me a 404 error.

After making a build, I made changes to `index.html`, I changed `<base href="/">` to `<base href="myWebsiteLink">`

I found a solution to this problem [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4607#issuecomment-279049115), where they said to make a `.htaccess` file in the `src` folder of an Angular project and update the `assets` array in the `angular.json` file. I did the same but the problem still persists when I hit refresh on the server.

Here is my content of `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

In `angular.json`, I made changes to the `assets` array in the `build` object as follows:

```
"build": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
   "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist",
      "index": "src/index.html",
      "main": "src/main.ts",
      "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
      "assets": [
         "src/assets",
         "src/.htaccess"
        ],
        ....
        ....
    }
```

Now, after building the build, in `dist` folder, the `.htaccess` file is shown to me. I pasted all these files onto the server using FileZilla.

**Page refresh issue is still occurring. It's still throwing 404.**

Please help me out if anyone has answer to it. THANKS.

Comment: try to use `hashLocationStrategy`. hope it will work for you.

Comment: @FarhatZaman `hashLocationStrategy` makes URL ugly(seems to me) by putting the hash(#) symbol in the URL. However, I found a glitch in my `.htaccess` file. The last line of code in this file should be a path to our `index.html` file. I modified that to the actual path of `index.html` on the server and everything works fine. THANKS